# Regex for Malaysian mobile phone Number

Tags: html, regex, preg-match, tel

This is the regex pattern i currently having for eg:01xxxxxxxx:

```
<input class="mdl-textfield__input" name="mobile_number" type="text" pattern="^(\+?6?01)[0-46-9]-*[0- 
9]{7,8}$">
```

I"m trying to allow not only 10 digits but also other formats as 11 digits(01xxxxxxxxx) and the office number eg:0xxxxxxxx.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Try `^\+?6?(?:01[0-46-9]-?(?:\d{7,8}|\d{4} \d{4})|0\d-\d{3} \d{4})$` https://regex101.com/r/2P4YAv/1

Comment: can I remove the dash and space from the format? Will it still work? I don't need the space n dash

Comment: Can you add some examples to the question what should match and what should not match?

Comment: I've edited the post. Pls do have a look and help me. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't need the hyphen `^\+?6?(?:01[0-46-9]\d{7,8}|0\d{8})$` https://regex101.com/r/lFYpyS/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an alternation `|` to match either there optional prefix part, omit matching the hyphens if you don't need them and as the second alternative match a 0 followed by 8 digits.

The pattern attribute is implicitly anchored, so you can omit `^` and `$`

```
\+?6?(?:01[0-46-9]\d{7,8}|0\d{8})
```

The pattern matches:

- `\+?6?` Match an optional `+` and an optional `6`
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `01[0-46-9]\d{7,8}` Match `01` then a digit except `5` and 7-8 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `0\d{8}` Match a `0` and 8 digits
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lFYpyS/1)

Answer (score 0):

For Both Malaysian Mobile and Landline numbers, that also handle 011 & 015 mobile prefix different length:

```
^6?(?:01[02346-9]\d{7}|011\d{8}|015\d{8}|03\d{8}|0[4-9]\d{7})$
```

Mobile numbers:

- 010/012/013/014/016/017/018/019 + seven digits
- 011 and 015 codes + eight digits

Landline numbers:

- code 03 + eight digits
- elsewhere + seven digits

Can try demo in:
https://regex101.com/r/Q3968C/2